# Why does dstat show zeroes for disk activity on my virtual private server running Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to monitor the number of disk reads and writes on my VPS (Rackspace in this case) running Ubuntu 9.04. I realize there are many tools to do this, but when using dstat 0.7 I tried the following command:

```
dstat -d
```

The output is just two columns of zeroes even when I upload a large file via scp that should be causing a large number of disk writes. Why is this, and how do I get dstat to correctly display the number of disk reads and writes?

Comment: Have you tried running `sync` after the upload?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It appears not to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dstat [don't work](http://bugzilla.openvz.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1298) in OpenVZ container. If you have access to host node, run:

```
# cat /proc/bc/556/ioacct 
read                           95322968064
write                        5023383080960
dirty                        5023383703552
cancel                       4862043058176
missed                                   0
syncs_total                             20
fsyncs_total                       1145489
fdatasyncs_total                   5842564
range_syncs_total                        0
syncs_active                             0
fsyncs_active                            0
fdatasyncs_active                        0
range_syncs_active                       0
vfs_reads                       7187138835
vfs_read_chars              56901570399853
vfs_writes                       777479552
vfs_write_chars              5636033128166
io_pbs                                 152
```